# Error when trying to build package from github with go

Tags: go, webhooks

I am trying to install package from github. https://github.com/adnanh/webhook

Version

```
$ go version
go version go1.17.5 linux/amd64
```

.profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Try:

```
$ go build github.com/adnanh/webhook
no required module provides package github.com/adnanh/webhook: go.mod file not found 
in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

Settings

```
$ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/root/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/root/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.17.5"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build586084061=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

where is a problem?

And I don't have go folder in /root/ with pkg and bin subfolders

Comment: `go build` builds code, `go install` installs commands. The README in the project is outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only [`go install`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-install) can work outside of any project (without a local .go.mod$

> Since Go 1.16, if the arguments have version suffixes (like `@latest` or `@v1.0.0`), `go install` builds packages in module-aware mode, ignoring the `go.mod` file in the current directory or any parent directory if there is one.
>
> This is useful for installing executables without affecting the dependencies of the main module.

[`go build`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) is meant to be used within a local project, with its `go.mod` dependencies list. It [compiles, but does not install](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/compile-install), a package.